# How does heatmap3 go from value to colour?

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm using the heatmap3 package for R to generate some gene expression data heatmaps.

**My question is: how are the values for the gene expression being "mapped" to colours?**

As an example of the same (reproducible) problem, lets use the example code in the vignette on the mtcars dataset:

```
library(heatmap3)    
heatmap3(mtcars,scale="col",margins=c(2,10),RowSideColors=RowSideColors, balanceColor = TRUE)
```

The legend shows that the colours range from approximately -2 to plus 3. If we use the Maserati Bora as an example

`mpg cyl   disp    hp   drat    wt       qsec   vs am gear carb
 15.0   8  301.0  335   3.54    3.570    14.60  0  1    5    8`

We can see in the heatmap that it has a bright red colour ie a score of ~3 for carb and a blue score of about -1.5 for qsec.

Looking at the other cars in the dataset, they have the following carb:

```
4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 2 1 1 2 2 4 2 1 2 2 4 6 8 2
```

So the Maserati Bora is definitely an outlier in terms of carbon, as is the Ferrari Dino (carb = 6), which is also as expected red in the heatmap.

Similarly, looking at the qseq

```
16.46 17.02 18.61 19.44 17.02 20.22 15.84 20.00 22.90 18.30 18.90 17.40 17.60 18.00 17.98 17.82 17.42 19.47 18.52 19.90 20.01 16.87 17.30 15.41 17.05 18.90 16.70 16.90 14.50 15.50 14.60 18.60
```

The Maserati's 14.60 is close to the minimum of 14.5, which is observed in the Ford Pantera L, which is also blue, as we'd expect.

**But how are we actually going from the value to the colour? What is the formula for calculating this z-score? And is it being averaged out on a per-car or a per-parameter (mpg, cyl etc) basis?**

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I just figured it out - but posting here in case others have the same problem:

It's using the basic z-score formula, so

```
(mtcars$qsec - mean(mtcars$qsec))/sd(mtcars$qsec)

(value - pop_mean(value))/ sd(value)
```